# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Tags: mysql, union

```
 SELECT a.paid, a.total, a.remain, a.date, a.patient_id FROM (
(SELECT paid, total, remain, date, patient_id FROM payment ) 
UNION 
(SELECT paid, total_need AS total, remain, date, patient_id FROM patient_vouchers ) 
 ) a
 WHERE a.patient_id ='.$patient_id.'
ORDER BY a.date ASC
```

I need to get records from two different tables order by date, so 
what is wrong in this sql statement to get me that error?!

Answer (score 0):

Look for your variables with different collations and align them, using for instance `COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Could you provide more information. I would need to know types of variables (if they are utf8_general_ci or others).